# ValueError Found array with 0 sample shape= (0,2) while a minimum of 1 is required by KMeans

Tags: python

I am new to logistic regression and cam across this error. Please help.

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

column_names =
["GENDER","AGE","INCOME","DOG_WHISPERER","DOGS_101","CATS_101","BAD_DOG",
"PUPPIES_VS_BABIES","PUPPY_BOWL"]

data =
pd.read_csv(/dbfs/FileStore/shared_uploads/eb1362@att.com/modified_uverse_data-
12.txt, sep="|", names=column_names, header=None)

subset_data = data[['GENDER', 'INCOME']]

subset_data['GENDER'] = subset_data['GENDER'].map({'Male': 0, 'Female': 1})

subset_data = subset_data.dropna()

X = subset_data.values

n_clusters = 3

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=42)

subset_data[]

subset_data['cluster'] = kmeans.fit_predict(X)

plt.scatter(subset_data['GENDER'], subset_data['INCOME'], c=subset_data['cluster'],
cmap='viridis')

plt.xlabel('Gender (0 for Male, 1 for Female)')

plt.ylabel('Income')

plt.title('Clustering of Gender vs. Income')

plt.show()